# Does "Circle(px,py d=d)" syntax for geospatial data dropped in Solr6? Since when and why?

Tags: solr, lucene, geospatial

we're using Solr in our service. Recently, we're working on upgrading Solr to Solr6 & spatial4j-v0.6. But we faced that geospatial data cannot be fed, it's rejected, that has syntax like `Circle(lat, lon, d=d)`.

It seems the syntax is dropped from Solr, but is it really dropped? Since when and why?? I couldn't find official statement that they dropped this syntax.

As for now, I find an option `format=LEGACY` for the `fieldType`, then Solr accepting data. But, are there any recommended, proper way to do with `Circle()`? Should we move to WKT/GeoJSON?

```
<fieldType
 name="location_rpt" 
 class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"   
 spatialContextFactory="org.locationtech.spatial4j.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
 format="LEGACY"/>
```

Comment: I just found this. Seems it was deprecated from 4.3... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6904

Comment: Wouldn't a [geofilt](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search) do what you are looking for?

Comment: @femtoRgon, Hi, thanks for the comment. From search POV, it hasn't changed I guess. Problem here is the format of the document.

Comment: Guys I'm facing `Unknown Shape definition [CIRCLE` if I don't add LEGACY option . Does someone have any idea how to use a circle ! Any explination