# Solr spatial search using an indexed field for radius?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, solr, lucene, geospatial

So I have an index of cities, looks something like this:

```
{
  "location": "41.388587, 2.175888",
  "name": "BARCELONA",
  "radius": 20
}
```

We have a few dozen of these. I need to be able to query this index with a single lat/lng combination and see if it falls inside one of our "cities".

The `location` property is the centre of the city, and the `radius` is the radius of the city in km (assuming all the cities are circles). We can also assume no cities overlap.

**How can I return whether or not a lat/lng combination falls within a city?**

For example, given the point `40.419691, -3.701254`, how can I determine if this falls within BARCELONA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it easily, in either Lucene, Solr or ES.

In Solr for example:

1. declare a type of SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType. This allows you to index different shapes, not just points
2. by using lat/long and the radius, you create an specific circle for each city, and you index that shape, in a field called 'shape' for example:

   ```
   {
     "location": "41.388587, 2.175888",
      "name": "BARCELONA",
      "shape": "CIRCLE (2.175888 41.388587, 20)"
   }
   ```
3. then you just query for any doc that intersects with your point (untested):

   ```
   fq=shape:"Intersects(40.419691 -3.701254)"
   ```

Be sure to check the docs and javadocs for the specific version of Lucene/Solr/ES you are using, as APIs have been changing in this space

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used that field type before. How can I use other fields as the center point and radius of an RPT?

Comment: I added an UNTESTED example, so you get an idea, but verify, order of lat/long, units of radius, and check javadocs, solr tests (good source of info) as these apis have evolved a lot in most releases

Comment: Yes, I'm using Solr 5.4 and have absolutely no idea how to get it working.

Comment: Your example is in JSON, but how would XML look to produce that?

Comment: Can CIRCLE be indexed in solr 6.1? Or 5.1? I found this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429495/does-circlepx-py-d-d-syntax-for-geospatial-data-dropped-in-solr6-since-when) saying that it was dropped and cannot for the life of me get Circle to work. I get an unknown shape definition error.  Is there a work around? Thanks.

Comment: To answer my own question... yes CIRCLE can be used with 6.1 (and probably 5.1) but you must add the legacy format attribute format="LEGACY" to the fieldtype. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092196/finding-solr-documents-that-intersect-with-a-defined-radius

And thank you @Persimmonium for your answer!

Comment: unable to parse shape given formats "lat,lon", "x y" or as WKT because java.text.ParseException: Unknown Shape definition [CIRCLE (2.175888 41.388587, 20)]