# solr distance between two points and distance less than miles field in each document

Tags: solr, solrnet

This is a reverse concept of spatial search, where candidates decide until which distance he can work.

I have a candidate c1 says he can work 20 miles from his location and c2 says he can work 10 miles from his location. If my search location is 10 miles form both candidates, my result should list the candidates with his distance and sort by distance.

My idea was get the distance form the search point to candidate point and check whether the distance meets the miles configured by each of the candidate.

I used q={!func}geodist() and sort=score asc, now i need to filter based on Miles configured in his document.
score<=Miles should be applied as a filter.

Can you guys help me resolving it, it would be a great help for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to index the candidates not with a point, but with a circle (center is their location, radius is the distance they are willing to travel).

Then you fq with a point that intersects with any of the circles. Look for details in this question: [Solr spatial search using an indexed field for radius?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789162/101762)

Comment: but mathematically a simplest solution would be finding the distance between two points and check whether the distance is less than the configured candidate's distance wright? Is this solutions performance is low, I am new to solr so wanted to know..

Comment: I don't have enough reputations to vote, please accept this comment as my vote, thank you so much for helping me out.... :)

Comment: can I know how to sort who is nearby the search location? So that we can achieve relevance to be based around nearest location.